# How to extract a variable from app.post in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

```
    app.post(' /', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
      res.render('load', {data: req.body});
      var token = req.body.token;
      require('./loader.js')
    });
```

How can I provide variable "token" to loader.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

export token variable and import it from 'loader.js'

```
app.post(' /', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
  res.render('load', {data: req.body});
  var token = req.body.token;
  module.exports.token = req.body.token;
});
```

In "./loader.js":

```
const { token } = require('<current_file>');
console.log(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your `loader.js` export a function that accepts a token argument.

Example:

```
// loader.js

const loader = (token) => {
    console.log(token);
}

module.exports = {
    loader
} 

// server.js

const {loader} = require("./loader");

...

app.post(' /', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
  res.render('load', {data: req.body});
  var token = req.body.token;
  loader(token);
});

...
```